# scikit multilearn: accuracy_score ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I want to predict samples that can be in more than 1 label at a time (multi label classification). So I use the [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml/index.html) library and have successfully fitted a classifier, and can even predict test data. It just fails at outputting the accuracy of the classifier.

My data (up to 1100 rows):

[image]

The dependent vars (the vars I'm predicting) are the last 4: **N/xN, Sex, Maturity**, and **CType**. The rest are the independent vars.

The accuracy I'm talking about is how close the classifier is to predicting all the labels.

Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance

# Prepare data
df = pd.read_csv("Data_Numeric.csv")
# remove crab_id for now
del df['Crab_id']

# independent vars: the rest
# dependent vars: N/xN, Gender, Maturity, CType
# n_samples = 1100
# n_features = 6
# n_labels = 4
X = df.iloc[:, :6].values
y = df.iloc[:, 6:df.shape[1]].astype(np.int64).values

X = sparse.csr_matrix(X)
y = sparse.csr_matrix(y, dtype=np.int64)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# generate model
classifier = BinaryRelevance(SVC())

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
y_pred_array = y_pred.toarray()

# my_data = X_test[0:4, :]
# my_data[0] = [64.7, 46, 12, 13, 0, 0]
# my_data_prediction = classifier.predict(my_data).toarray()
# my_data_true = y_test[0:4, :].toarray()

# error here
score = accuracy_score(y_test.toarray(), y_pred.toarray())
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 42, in <module>
  File "/home/f4ww4z/anaconda3/envs/ayah/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 185, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/f4ww4z/anaconda3/envs/ayah/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 97, in _check_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

**`y_test`**

```
>>> y_test
<330x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 578 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`y_test.toarray()`, shape is `330x4`:

[image: y_test]

**`y_pred`**

```
>>> y_pred
<330x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.longlong'>'
    with 408 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

`y_pred.toarray()`:

[image: y_pred]

How do I correctly see the accuracy of the classifier?

Comment: You need to (1) define what multiclass accuracy means to you (2) write your code.  For the (1) it might be anything from correctly guessing all the labels to correctly guessing top n.

Comment: how does your data look like? share a snippet of the data. as well as how does y_true looks like?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Flika205 I've added them in the description.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold

clf = BinaryRelevance(SVC())
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

scores = cross_validate(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=k_fold, scoring=['accuracy'])
```

OR

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
```

By using cross validation methods you can obtain the 5 accuracy scores and then take a mean of them.

You can go by basic by using a MultioutputClassifier and RandomForestClassifier

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
clf=MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42,class_weight="balanced"))
k_fold = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

scores = cross_validate(clf, X_train_tf, y_train, cv=k_fold, scoring=['f1_weighted'])
```

Maybe this will help you :)